How can I measure the effect of BigQuery history based optimizations?
I have enabled the BigQuery preview feature history based optimizations. I can see a bunch of queries in the JOBS_BY_PROJECT information schema view have the following details:
{"optimizations":[{"parallelism_adjustment":"applied"}]}
The question is; how can I numerically measure the impact of this optimization and therefore its benefit?

According to the documentation you can review what job has applied with history-based optimisation
SELECT
  job_id,
  query_info.optimization_details
FROM `project_name.region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE job_id = 'sample_job'
LIMIT 1;

For the actual numbers I believe there is no direct way to see the comparison but you can query performance for insight and <br>average slot utilzation here:
SELECT
  SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) AS avg_slots
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE
  -- Filter by the partition column first to limit the amount of data scanned.
  -- Eight days allows for jobs created before the 7 day end_time filter.
  creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  AND job_type = 'QUERY'
  AND statement_type != 'SCRIPT'
  AND end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

